# How to test that a PHP Closure passed as a parameter to a function has been called exact number of times

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I am trying to find a way to check that Closure function passed to a method in my unit test has been called exactly one time. But Closure class in PHP is declared as final and I get the following error message when I run it : "Class "Closure" is declared "final" and cannot be mocked."

Here is a code example. I am trying to check that valueProducer() has been called exactly one time.

```
class PoorCache{
    protected $storage;

    /**
     * Returns value from cache and if the value lacks puts it into the cache storage
     * @param string $key
     * @param Closure $valueProducer produces a value for storage, i.e. makes a request to DB
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function remember($key, Closure $valueProducer)
    {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $this->storage))
            {
                    return $this->storage[$key];
            }

            $this->storage[$key] = $valueProducer();
            return $this->storage[$key];
    }
}

class PoorCacheTest extends TestCase {
    public function testRemeber(){
        $mockedValueProducer = $this->getMock(\Closure::class);
        $mockedValueProducer->expects($this->once())->method('call');

        $cache = new PoorCache();
        $cache->remember('myKey', $mockedValueProducer);
        $cache->remember('myKey', $mockedValueProducer);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Interesting suggestion for mocking closures with PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues/257)

Comment: I didn't know `Closure` was `final`, interesting. One thing you could try is to remove the `Closure` type hint and add a PHP test based on something like `!is_callable()` at the start of that method. You'd have to play around with how the mocked class becomes callable (maybe a partial mock on something that implements call magic? Would have to play here...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Removing Closure from method spec would definitely solve the problem. But it is a bypass. I was wonder if someone knew straightforward solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a non existent class double to which you would implement the `__invoke` method. But the double will not be an instance of `\Closure` so you would have to remove the `\Closure` type hint of your `remember` method.

```
// Create double
$double = $this->getMockBuilder('NonExistentClass')
    ->setMethods(['__invoke'])
    ->getMock();

// Set expectations
$double->expects($this->once())->method('__invoke');

// Test
$double();
```

Comment: great answer - the key is remembering the magic method __invoke.

Comment: if anyone wants to pass as a callable to a method, `[$double, '__invoke']`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the result of the given closure, store the closure and then call it once.

Like this:

```
class PoorCache {

    protected $storage;
    private $called = [];

    /**
     * Returns value from cache and if the value lacks puts it into the cache storage
     * @param string $key
     * @param Closure $valueProducer produces a value for storage, i.e. makes a request to DB
     * @return null
     */
    public function remember($key, Closure $valueProducer)
    {
            // store $valueProducder Closure
            $this->storage[$key] = $valueProducer;

            if(isset($this->called[$key])) {
                unset($this->called[$key]); 
            }
            return null;
    }

    // call producer closure by key 
    public function callProducer($key)
    {
        if(isset($this->storage[$key]))  {

           // check if $key has been called 
           // if true returns false
           if(isset($this->called[$key])) {
                return false;
           }

           // add $key to called array 
           $this->called[] = $key;
           // call closure
           return ($this->storage[$key])();
        }
    }
}

class PoorCacheTest extends TestCase {

    public function testRemeber(){
        $mockedValueProducer = $this->getMock(\Closure::class);
        $mockedValueProducer->expects($this->once())->method('call');

        $cache = new PoorCache();

        // store closure once 
        $cache->remember('myKey', $mockedValueProducer);

        // store closure twice 
        // this is going to override the own before it 
        // since they both have the same key 
        $cache->remember('myKey', $mockedValueProducer);

        // call producer once 
        $cache->callProducer('myKey');

        // call producer twice
        // NOTE: this going to return false since 'myKey' 
        // has already been called 
        $cache->callProducer('myKey');
    }
}
```

Comment: its a function name so it  doesn't have any effects also i copied the code that he submitted i didn't bother changing the name

Comment: Ah, fair enough. On another note, could you add to your answer a summary of what you are proposing? We encourage answers that explain a solution, rather than just something to paste. That makes it more helpful to future readers.

Comment: updated, now calling the Coluser twice gonna return false the second time

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Solution suggested by you can make my example work. However, I looked for a way to mock `Closure` specified in method parameter. My code example is only a background for this purpose. It does not have a real value, so no need to make it work bypassing the problem with `Closure`.